# Cannot access elasticsearch_dsl meta.id

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch-dsl

I want to use meta ID field to add a new index/field based on the searched data, but I cannot access meta.id field. What should I do? Here is the code below -

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch  
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search  

es = Elasticsearch(Host="http://localhost", PORT=9200)  

request = Search(using=es, index='internal', doc_type="doc")  

response = request.scan()  

for each in response:  
....alert = each.to_dict()  
....print(alert["id"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by `cannot access`? What happens if you do `each.meta.id` in your `for` loop?

Comment: each.meta.id this did work. BTW I love your video and codes. Thanks for your time!